# Already put if notEOF and bof and still get an error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, adodb, eof, recordset

I am programming in Vb.net and using access. I used adodb to connect it.
I am having a problem about eof and bof. I try to code in a way that the program tells the user that it is already the last row and cannot go to the next row.

```
Private Sub nav()
        If retVal Then
            lblQuestion.Visible = True

            lblQuestion.Text = rs.Fields("Question").Value
            lblType.Text = rs.Fields("Type").Value
            lblGroup.Text = rs.Fields("Group").Value

            If lblTtype.Text = "d" Then
                txtAnswer.Visible = True
                comboOption.Visible = True
           ElseIf lblTipo.Text = "o" Then
                comboOption.Visible = True
                txtAnswer.Visible = false

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            rs.MoveNext()
            nav()
        Else
            MsgBox("This is the last Question")
        End If
    End Sub
```

when it reaches the last row, still goes like it is not the last row. I mean, it tries to go to the next row, even with the "If not rs.EOF".

thanks in advance.

Comment: You really ought to avoid that method of data access altogether if you can.  If you already have code that came from VB6 then that's justification for sticking with it.  If you have a bad boss that insists that you write VB.NET code like it was VB6 then you're stuck with it.  Otherwise, you ought to be using ADO.NET in VB.NET, which means `DataTables`, data adapters and data readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for`rs.Eof`**after**`rs.MoveNext`too, as if you are in last row and move to next, you reach`rs.Eof`where`rs.Fields`contain no data.

Just add another check before`nav()`:

```vb
Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveNext()
        If Not rs.Eof Then
            nav()
        Else
            rs.MovePrevious()
            MsgBox("This is the last Question")
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```